# Timeout when running docker-composer build

Tags: hadoop, docker, hive, docker-compose

I try to install Apache Hive via docker and I tried to run docker-compose build in /home/user/Stažené/docker-hive-master directory as root. When I run docker-compose build, I get this error:

```
Building hive-metastore
Step 1/24 : FROM bde2020/hadoop-base:1.1.0-hadoop2.8-java8
ERROR: Service 'hive-metastore' failed to build: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

I would like to know why this timeout happens. How I can resolve it?

Comment: I have docker-compose version 1.16.1, build 6d1ac21. It means that docker-compose is installed correctly. I want to know what causes the timeout when installing hive via docker-compose.

Comment: It's not a Hive problem, it can't connect to Docker registry